# Snapchat on ubuntu touch?

Tags: installation, software-center, ubuntu-touch

Is it imposible to downloade snapchat on ubuntu touch? I'm wondering if I should download ubuntu touch on my nexus 4 but if is not possible to download the snapchat from the softwear center, i think I will not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an application which is not developed (and may not in a long time) for Ubuntu (any version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not, the developer has made no move to make a Ubuntu Touch application, and probably won't for a long time (if ever).
Though if you are asking these kinds of questions, I don't think Ubuntu Touch is for you, it is very raw and not really ready for a consumer daily usage, more for developers who want to make applications. I disrecommend you flash Ubuntu Touch to your device until it has a stable consumer version.

Comment: Additionally, the Linux/Open Source community generally doesn't support DMR, and we shouldn't support anything like this because it gives people a feeling of security that does not exist. Anything that shows up on a computer screen can be copied, and there is no way to prevent it.